# I wanted to convert the following C# Code to Python Code

Tags: python, c#

Friends how to convert the following C# code to Python:

```
class BaseClass {
    //some member(s)
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
   //some member(s)
}

class Program {
    public static void Main(){ 
        BaseClass bc = new DerivedClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to convert? 1) write python code. 2) check if it does the same as your c# code. 3) if not: go to 1.... alternatively: use [search engine of your choice] and find a tutorial among the lines of "absolute basics of python"

Answer (score 0):

If you are a C# programmer, and want an introduction to Python, there are several resources on the net. A quick search found a [presentaton](http://sddconf.com/brands/sdd/library/An_introduction_to_Python_for_the_CSharp_developer.pdf) with good examples, including conversions of class declarations (just search for `class` in the PDF). Multiple other resources are bound to exist, just [search for them](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+for+c%23+programmers&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL793IL793&oq=python+for+C%23+pro&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l6.5697j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseClass:
    //some member(s)

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    //some member(s)

bc=DerivedClass()
```

This is just a example. For more information check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp).

Answer (score 0):

To define a class in python, you use the syntax `class ClassName:` or `class ClassName(BaseName):`. Then we define a main method(`def main():`) that will be run. Finally, if we tell the interpreter to run the main method if this file is being run as the main process (`if __name__ == "__main__"`).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class BaseClass:
    def baseMethod(self):
        return "base"

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def derivedMethod(self):
        return "derived"

def main():
    bc = DerivedClass()
    print(bc.baseMethod())
    print(bc.derivedMethod())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```